# Fetching data to a rendered view with PDO

Tags: php, templates

I've been building my own MVC framework, and i'm facing problems fetching data to a rendered view, I have this Workspace controller:

`<?php class Workspace extends Controller {
    public function Index() {
        $this->title = "Workspace";
        $users_model = $this->loadModel('users');
        $users = $users_model->getUsers();
        $this->build('master@Workspace');
    }
} ?>`

where the `$users` function is an array of data fetched from the `$users_model` model

on the rendered view I use this code:

`<?php froeach($users as $user) { echo $user->name } ?>`

when I try to see the page I got the following error:  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

It seems the problem has something to do with my build function, because if I directly require the view the warning is not displayed.

I hope I were clear enough, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$users_model->getUsers();
```

this is not returning an `array`.

You could try to use `var_dump()` on it, and see what's going on.

Or in your code, you could use `is_array()` to see if you can use `foreach()` on it.